# How to find the css version?

Tags: css

How do I find the version of CSS that I am using?

Answer (score 21):

Although the CSS specification is defined in several versions (v2, 2.1, 3), the CSS version isn't really relevant to the developer; you need to be more concerned with which web browsers support a given feature.

It is useful to know that a given feature was defined in CSS2, 2.1 or 3 because that can give you an idea of how old the feature is, and therefore how likely it is that browsers will support it -- for example `border-radius` is a CSS3 feature, so browsers more than a couple of years old may not support it fully.

You can find out what CSS features are supported in which browsers from the following sites:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html
- http://caniuse.com/

Comment: For us, there is some change in the default value of the position property in CSS which is collapsing the whole design when printing it.

This happened after the chrome update.

Answer (score 4):

The version is only defined by the CSS selectors, propreties and attributes that you use.

You are free to mix elements of CSS 1, 2 and 3 in any styles that you write.

You can refer to the CSS specifications to see more details.  The specifications and drafts at the W3C is available via this index: http://www.w3schools.com/w3c/w3c_css.asp

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition of what @Craig said.

In my .net 2.0 framework I have a property to show scroll bars. As I want just the vertical, I've added both properties and, if the browser that user is using support this new CSS 3.0 property (**overflow-x**), he will see just the vertical one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's nothing in CSS code that specifies the version.  Browsers are designed to interpret one or more versions of CSS at runtime.  Therefore, I would imagine that you would need to [get the version of the browser via javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) and then determine what version of CSS is understood by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) instead - check the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Browser_Feature_Detection) to understand the principle.
On Internet Explorer you might find [compatMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533687%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [documentMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28VS.85%29.aspx) useful.