# How would I know what version of CSS a site is using?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the css version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440868/how-to-get-the-css-version)

Just having a think if I was looking at a site how would I know what version of CSS the site is using? Does it matter?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Are you asking how to look at a stylesheet and determine what features it's using (e.g. descendant selectors, or particular CSS properties), associate those features with the various CSS specifications, and then take the maximum of those to determine if it there were any CSS1, CSS2, CSS2.1, or CSS3 features used?

Comment: @samccone Because the question is (in my opinion) ambiguous/confusing. A website doesn't use a particular CSS version; I'm not even sure what that means, other than my above guess.

Answer (score 3):

It dosen't really matter, but if you'd still like to check, use the W3C Validation Service, but make sure to change the 'Profile' option under the 'More Options' menu to 'No Special profile'.

Then enter the URL or directly copy and paste the CSS to the Validator, and press validate. It'll tell you the version of CSS on the top of the page.

Link: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_uri+with_options

Answer (score 2):

It can use css1, css2, css3 features. You should determine it by looking at the source code, and possibly googling the features.

You can't find it, because it is nowhere defined, if you make a css file of your own, you do not define the version.